# What's wso2 deployment pattern

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I downloaded wso2am-4.0.0.zip from [here](https://wso2.com/api-manager/#) and runned by command "api-manager.bat start". It works fine. I heard there were some wso2am deployment patterns , but I didn't find where there were defined. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 deployment patterns recommended by WSO2. The most used deployment patterns in a production environment are the Simple Scalable Deployment and the Simple Scalable with Traffic Manager seperation.

For more information, please refer [1]. For information on setting up a distributed system, refer [2].

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-overview/

[2] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/understanding-the-distributed-deployment-of-wso2-api-m/